# Detect control overlapping in Flex 4 while an object is moving?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder, collision-detection, overlapping

I have this small project [HERE](http://www.shedosurashu.com/aurum-aeon/aa_test_walk_engine.html). Right now it barely does anything but make the character move.

I move the character by using **<s:Move>**. Now as you can see on the link to my project page, it moves to where you point the mouse and click. I want to be able to stop the character from moving if it hits another object or in this case, the "tree". Is there a script in AS3 that will let me detect collisions or controls that are overlapping each other?

If my question is a bit lacking information, please comment back here and I'll update it with more details as you need.

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DisplayObjects have a a method called [hitTestObject(obj:DisplayObject)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) that tests when one object overlaps another. You can read about it in the [Tree class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html), [DisplayObject class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html), or any class that extends DisplayObject.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at it! :)